# How does Vim display :ls results (curses/cooked mode)

Tags: vim, ncurses

When I am inside Vim and type `:ls`, Vim lists the buffers. Most likely it is going into "cooked mode" using `def_prog_mode()` and `endwin()`. I'd like to know how it print the values. The best I've come out with is using `system("echo ....")` which would be quite laborious.
I've tried `printf` - no effect, and `printw`.

I need to do the same kind of thing in my apps, and rather than create Windows or popups I would like to list internal information like Vim does.

Here's a sample of what I've tried, from http://gist.github.com/587622

```
#include <ncurses.h>

// it seems system echo is the only way to print some stuff in cooked mode
// i am trying to figure out how VIM displays the result of :ls

int main()
{       
        initscr();                      /* Start curses mode              */
        printw("Hello World !!! Hit a key\n");    /* Print Hello World              */
        refresh();                      /* Print it on to the real screen */
        getch();
        def_prog_mode();                /* Save the tty modes             */
        endwin();                       /* End curses mode temporarily    */
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            system("echo inside cooked mode");
        }
        //printf("helllow there\n");
        //system("/bin/ls");              /* Do whatever you like in cooked mode */
        //system("read");
        //system("/bin/sh");              /* Do whatever you like in cooked mode */
        //system("echo hit a key");              /* Do whatever you like in cooked mode */
        //printw("Hit a key buddy\n");    /* Print Hello World              */
        reset_prog_mode();              /* Return to the previous tty mode*/
        getch();
                                        /* stored by def_prog_mode()      */
        refresh();                      /* Do refresh() to restore the    */
                                        /* Screen contents                */
        printw("After cooked mode.\nKey to quit");     /* Back to curses use the full    */
        getch();
        refresh();                      /* capabilities of curses         */
        endwin();                       /* End curses mode                */

        return 0;
}
```

Compile it using:

```
gcc -o a.out -lncurses a.c && ./a.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to flush the stdio buffer using `fflush`. That is, after using `printf` to write some text, call `fflush(stdout)` to make sure the text gets sent to the terminal. ncurses is probably calling `setbuf` or `setvbuf` to enable block buffered IO to the terminal and this is not considered part of the tty modes saved and restored.

Comment: Yup worked great! Didn't think of `fflush` since I am actually using ruby and haven't written in C for 18 years. Thanks.

Comment: I've got this working fine. However, I see that in microemacs when you type C-x c to go to shell, it does not clear the screen. Vim does and so does my prog, due to `endwin()`. If I remove `endwin` the screen is not cleared. but upon return, it remains scrolled up. I've tried def_shell_mode (???) but that messes up. So how to keep the existing windows and panels showing, and revert cleanly. thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you call setbuf(stdout, NULL) you don't have to call fflush(stdout) every time...

setbuf is declared in the header stdio.h